Riemannian submersions and associated fibre bundles
My question is as follows, it is related to the chapter of Associated Fibre Bundles from [1].
Let $(X, g_X)$ and $(Y, g_Y)$ be two smooth manifolds and let $H$ be a Lie group which acts smoothly on both $X$ and $Y$. We denote such actions as $x \mapsto x\cdot h^{-1}$ and $y \mapsto h\cdot y$, respectively, for each $h \in H$, $x \in X$, $y \in Y$.
Assume that the action of $H$ on $X$ is free and proper, which implies that $X/H$ is a smooth manifold.
We define the action of $H$ on $X\times Y$ as $(x, y) \mapsto (x\cdot h^{-1}, h\cdot y)$. Again, we can define the quotient manifold
$$
X \times_H Y := \{\{(x \cdot h^{-1}, h\cdot y) : h \in H\} : (x, y) \in X \times Y\}.
$$
This way, we can define four fibre bundles (cf. [1]):
$$
\begin{matrix}
X \times Y & \xrightarrow{\pi_3} & X \times_H Y\\
\ \downarrow \pi_1& & \ \downarrow \pi_4\\
X & \xrightarrow{\pi_2} & X/H
\end{matrix}
$$
and $\pi_2 \circ \pi_1 = \pi_4 \circ \pi_3$.
If one endows $X \times Y$ with the product metric $g_{X \times Y}$, then $\pi_1$ is a Riemannian submersion.
Furthermore, if $H$ acts isometrically both on $X$ and $X \times Y$, there exist metrics on $X/H$ and $X \times_H Y$ making $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$ Riemannian submersions.
My question is: with respect to these metrics, is $\pi_4$ a Riemannian submersion?
I have been able to prove that if one takes a vector in $X/H$ and lifts it horizontally with respect to $\pi_2$ first and then with respect to $\pi_1$, it is horizontal with respect to $\pi_3$, but cannot prove that it will also be horizontal with respect to $\pi_4$.
[1] Duistermaat, J. J., & Kolk, J. A. (2012). Lie groups. Springer Science & Business Media.

Note that $\pi_4$ is short (= 1-Lipschitz).
Indeed, it is a composition of two short maps $X\times_H Y\to (X/H)\times (H\backslash Y)\to X/H$.
(The second space is not a manifold, but it does not matter.)
Now, as you stated, given a vector $V$ in the tangent bundle of $X/H$, we can lift it horizontally to $X$ and to $X\times Y$, then map it by $d\pi_3$ to $X\times_H Y$.
This way we get a lift, say $W$, of $V$ to $X\times_H Y$.
By construction $|W|\leqslant |V|$.
Since $\pi_4$ is short, we have $|W|=|V|$.
So, $W$ is a horizontal lift of $V$.

Thank you for your message! I have a question: how does the fact that $|W| = |V|$ imply that $W$ is a horizontal lift? (I am assuming that both $X/H$ and $X \times_H Y$ are endowed with the metrics making $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$ Riemannian submersions, respectively). Could it not happen that there existed another $W'$ which is the horizontal lift of $V$ by $\pi_4$ and such that $|W'| \neq |V|$?

@Pablo yes --- if it is not perpendicular to the fiber, then $|W|>|V|$.
